# Get list of user id's from a users Twitter followers using Tweepy

Tags: twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I have written the following code to get a list of all the Twitter followers a username has but I would like to just get the user_id instead as this allows me to do a lot more within the rate limit for the API. How do I change this code to just print the user_ids?

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(key, secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

screen_name = "twitterusername"
  
friends = api.friends_ids(screen_name) 
  
print(screen_name + " is following :") 
for friend in friends: 
    print(api.get_user(friend).screen_name)
```

I have all of the correct authorisation keys and tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The User object has an `id` field

```
print(screen_name + " is following :") 
for friend in friends: 
  print(api.get_user(friend).id)
```

If you are interested in the IDs only of the users be aware that `api.friends_ids` returns already a list of IDs

```
friends = api.friends_ids('screen_name')
logging.info(friends)
# output: [324343434, 134343234567,...]
```